# Add software to Macrium Reflect Windows PE rescue media

Tags: dism, winpe, macrium, windows-pe

I have created a WinPE 10 rescue medium on a flash drive and would like to add additional software (PortableApps, Veracrypt, Sysinternals tools) and drivers. When I just copy the portable executables to a folder on the rescue disk and try to run it on the WinPE CMD, I get an error message **the image file is valid but it is for a machine type other than the current machine**.

I understand that the [proper process](https://forum.macrium.com/Topic1587.aspx) to add software is to:

1. download WinPE .wim file
2. mount file with dism, copy executables
3. load custom .wim in Macrium and save image to drive

This is a cumbersome process, especially as the original system I am trying to work on is not available.

Is there a way to:

- directly mount the file sources/boot.wim on the flash drive on another machine to add software using step 2 above, without going through the Macrium step 3?
- get software to run directly on WinPE without going through dism? It would be nice to be able to add the programs to a 2nd stick to be able to add missing software on the fly.

Comment: To my knowledge WinRE x64 cannot run x86 software only x64 software since it does not have WoW64.  You can mount the .WIM within Windows, but that won't tell you if the image is functional, which is the reason you have to actually apply it to a partition in order to test it.

Comment: I think that is true. I edited to make it clear that the error message "the image file is valid but it is for a machine type other than the current machine" happens when I try to run the executable on WinPE. Do you know what dism does to the executables? Does a normal installer come with both versions and dism strips one? I even tried putting Veracrypt portable on the disk after unzipping on Windows, but I still got the same error message.

Comment: “Do you know what dism does to the executables?” - Your question doesn’t make sense; “Does a normal installer come with both versions and dism strips one?” - What? please explain in specific detail by editing your question instead of confusing commentary; “I even tried putting Veracrypt portable on the disk after unzipping on Windows, but I still got the same error message.” - Sounds like you didn’t have the appropriate architecture. Trying to customize WinPE is not for the faint of heart, it’s difficult, on purpose it’s not a daily driver solution. Only exact error messages are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "slip-streaming" is a pain. It might be easier to just use a prebuilt WinPE or RE environment, such as [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/),which has an old version of Reflect, or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/ultimate-boot-cd/about/).

Another alternative is to add another, FAT32 or NTFS, partition to the Macrium Reflect rescue media, and put any *portable* software there. Sysinternals and Nirsoft tools, [Veracrypt Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/security/veracrypt-portable), [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) should work well there; just browse with the WinRE ("Macrium Reflect") Explorer to the added partition. *In some cases you might need to [mount that partition](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-mount-drive-windows-10) from CMD.*

A third option is to make a live Windows USB device with [persistence](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive), retaining any changes made after booting from it. This allows the *full windows 10 OS* to run from USB, and any changes made in a session is *retained*. That means that software not only can be *copied* onto the USB drive, but it can be *installed*, making Registry changes and setting up folders and paths. There are two issues with doing this, though:

- Running from ordinary flash memory USB drives is *slow*, because writing to flash is generally slower than to even HDD.
- The USB OS will have drivers for the machine on which it was built, and might not work as well (or at all) on another.

Comment: I tried to copy Veracrypt portable onto the same drive and tried to run it from the internal CMD, but I got a strange error message (don't know the exact wording) "image ok, but wrong architecture". This is strange, because it is a 64b Win 10 image and the portable apps run on the same system I used to create the rescue medium.

Comment: Did you put the app in *another partition*? BTW, Live boot USB's with *persistence* can retain changes, so the software can be copied *after* booting, and even installed, if need be.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't make it work. It seems the problem is that many of the portable apps are just x86 versions. The ultimate boot cd you mentioned was good enough for my purpose. Thanks!